# freindly_id returns 0 for named url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

Using the line:
`@post = Post.friendly.where!(:board_id=>params[:board_id]).find(params[:id])`
to separate posts `:board_id` returns a `0` when the url is `/board1/thread/1/`, but returns the correct value of `1` when the url is `/1/thread/1/`

How can I get the correct value of either `1`, or possibly the board slug of `board1`?

Edit:

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :replies, through: :posts
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, :replies
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :pid, :use => :scoped, :scope => :id
  after_create :set_pid
  def set_pid
    post_max = self.board.posts.maximum(:pid)
    reply_max = self.board.replies.maximum(:pid)
    if post_max.to_i < reply_max.to_i
       self.update_attributes(:pid => reply_max.to_i + 1) 
    else
       self.update_attributes(:pid => post_max.to_i + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're setting up friendly id for both your Post and Board models?

Comment: @pgaspar updated the post to include both models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Unique_Slugs_by_Scope) something like this should work for you:

```
@post = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id]).posts.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Be aware that this will execute two queries - one for finding the board, and another for finding the post within that board.

There are ways to do this in a single query (for example with a left outer join), although they would introduce coupling with the friendly id configuration you use on the Board model. Example:

```
Post.includes(:board).where('boards.slug' => params[:board_id]).friendly.find(params[:id])
```